# Filter & Delete rows of data based off of column value fast! (Google Sheets)

Tags: performance, google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-sheets, formula

Is there a way to filter the data in column Q off my google sheet faster then reading line one by one. There is daily about 400+ lines it needs to scan through and I need to delete every row of data if the data in column Q is less than 1 right now watching it, it takes about 10+ minutes.

```
  function UpdateLog() {

  var returnSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('CancelRawData');
  var rowCount = returnSheet.getLastRow();

  for (i = rowCount; i > 0; i--) {
    var rrCell = 'Q' + i;
    var cell = returnSheet.getRange(rrCell).getValue();
    if (cell < 1 ){
      returnSheet.deleteRow(i);
    }
  }
  {

SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(" Congratulations, your data has been updated", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
function UpdateLog() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  let d = 0;
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (!isNaN(r[16]) && r[16] < 1){
      sh.deleteRow(i + 1 - d++);
    } 
  });
}
```

This is a bit quicker

```
function UpdateLog() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues().filter(r => !isNaN(r[16]) && r[16] < 1);
  sh.clearContents();
  sh.getRange(1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

Comment: The second one is moving fast but only leaving the -1 and removing the header. it is really fast though

Comment: How many header lines do you have and what row does day start on?

Comment: 1 header that is frozen at all time - also when that runs it on leaves the -1 and 0, I need it to only leave the value of 1 and delete everything less than 1